# Phoenix 1.0 to 1.2: Unchecked dependencies for environment dev

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am updating Phoenix from 1.0 to 1.2
I followed the steps to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1 and then 1.1.x to 1.2.0

Whenever I try to compile I am getting the following error:

```
Unchecked dependencies for environment dev:
* phoenix_pubsub_redis (Hex package)
  the dependency does not match the requirement "~> 2.1", got "1.0.0"
* phoenix_html (Hex package)
  the dependency does not match the requirement "~> 2.6", got "2.2.0"
* phoenix (Hex package)
  the dependency does not match the requirement "~> 1.2.0", got "1.0.3"
* phoenix_ecto (Hex package)
  the dependency does not match the requirement "~> 3.0-rc", got "1.2.0"
** (Mix) Can't continue due to errors on dependencies
```

Does anyone know what is going on or how this could be fixed?

Comment: Did you make sure to run `mix deps.update <list of packages>` as mentioned in the 1.1 -> 1.2 guide? http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/upgrading-from-11x-to-120

Comment: Yeah I ran that. It was something with the cache on my machine. I ran `mix deps.clean --all` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

The issue was somewhere in the cache on my machine.

I ran `mix deps.clean --all` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Been getting similar errors not specific to phoenix, but found that deleting the `_build` directory and running `mix deps.get` helped remove those errors.

Running `mix deps.clean --all` wasn't enough.

Elixir version 1.14.2.